# What style of chair are Morpheus and Neo using?

Tags: the-matrix, props

What is the name/style of the pair of chairs with armrests that are used by Morpheus and Neo in the scene of the red and blue pills? What type of chairs are they?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This style of chair is called a Chesterfield Wingback Armchair.

Here is one on [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Chesterfield-Queen-Anne-High-Back-Wing-Chair-Oxblood-Leather-Footstool-/141956892526) with a footstool.

[image]

Comment: @Valorum I added it, it appears that sometimes they are called Chesterfields, Wingbacks, or both.

Comment: I was under the impression that a chesterfield was an armchair with arms and a back [of a similar height](https://web.archive.org/web/20120321203901/http://www.distinctivechesterfields.com/the-history-of-the-chesterfield-sofa.html) and that the "wingback" was an addition to the Chesterfield to denote a high, semi-circular backing.

Comment: Why do you people know so much about chairs?

Comment: @Wadcheber - Because knowing about Scifi will only get you sofa.

Comment: @Valorum if I could bounty you for that pun, I would do.

Comment: I'm talking about the sofa in the first meeting between them, no the one where he is jackin the the hovercraft. The scene with the pills, I think that the sofa in the picture above is another one.

Comment: @Feuergeist The Pill Scene uses the same chairs as in the Construct scene. You can see the wooden armrest ends are the same. https://chancecard.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/vlcsnap-00001.png http://static1.businessinsider.com/image/52e2b5826bb3f7d6610fd548/kia-parodies-a-memorable-matrix-scene-in-its-new-super-bowl-teaser.jpg

Comment: Wingback = the style of chair;
Chesterfield = the tufted buttons;
Oxblood = color

Comment: “There is no footstool” — [Dumbledore](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/Jeffrey_Wright_cropped_by_David_Shankbone.jpg/220px-Jeffrey_Wright_cropped_by_David_Shankbone.jpg)